# TeamViewer Replacement

Tags: open-source, remote-access

Fed up with TeamViewer, need replacement to support elderly Aunt and Uncle in distant city, I am retired and do not charge anybody, yet they are claiming I am a commercial business. I would pay but can't even afford TV.

Comment: What is your price range? How much are you willing to pay? Open Source solutions won't be easy enough for elderly Aunt and Uncle.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please also don't forget to mention the OS involved on both end. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for details, then [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: If you are not running a commercial person and are not otherwise breaking their t&c' s, contact them and explain your case and they will review it. Same thing happen to me about a month ago - was restored in a few days.

Comment: That is what I would expect.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest TightVNC.  Its free, a bit laggy but will be fine for your use.

Comment: I will upvote, because I have used it for decades & can't find better. However, you ***might*** have a problem with TightVNC, simply because the aunt’s PC will most likely be behind a router, requiring some port forwarding, which TeamViewer takes care of for you. I would do as @CJM, the commentator above, and appeal to them. If that fails, and for use on aLAN, you simply can’t beat TightVNC.

Comment: I was assuming that he could visit his aunt once to set it up.  :-)